# dynamic table with pivot operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

### **My table**

```
cname |  ename 
------+-------      
aaa   |   aaaa      
raj   |   tesfsa    
raj   |   aaaa
```

need to look like this

```
cname   |   interviewer1   |   interviewer2  
--------+------------------+------------------- 
raj     |       aaaa       |       tesfsa   
aaa     |       aaaa       |
```

cname can have multiple interviewer(dynamically)... this is the issue..

i think it need to use dynamic pivot operator, i don have much knowledge in pivot.. please help me guys...

Comment: is anyone here to help me...

Comment: Is there a max number of interviewers?

Comment: may be 6 interviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/864d4/69)

This is what you want exactly.

```
create procedure pro
as
BEGIN

DECLARE @colsName VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #temp
( 
     cname VARCHAR(50),
     ename VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
select (c.Firstname+c.Lastname) as cname,(e.EmployeeFName+e.EmployeeLName) as ename  
from CandidateProfile c inner join JobApplied ja on (ja.ProfileId = c.ProfileID)
inner join JobInterview ji on (ja.JobApplyUID = ji.JobApplyUID) 
inner join Employees e on (ji.InterviewBy = e.EmployeeID) 
group by c.Firstname+c.Lastname,InterviewTimeFrom,e.EmployeeFName+e.EmployeeLName




SELECT @colsName = COALESCE(@colsName + ', ','') + colName 
FROM   (select distinct ename + ' AS interviewer' +
convert(varchar, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ename ASC)) as colName
FROM #temp) a


SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ', ','') + ename 
FROM   (select distinct ename
FROM #temp) b


SET @query = N'SELECT cname, '+
@colsname +'
FROM #temp
PIVOT
(
MAX(ename)
FOR ename IN
( '+@cols +' )
) AS pvt'


EXECUTE(@query)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

END

Comment: @Kasirajan, what you mean by direct code? this is the minimum line that I can think of, perhaps put inside a stored procedure ? and I am pretty sure you can't do it with 1 line unless your pivot table have fixed value

Comment: @Kasirajan, just select distinct your ename will do right ?

Comment: @Kasirajan, I still din't get you, if you distinct ename it will get the count right ? select count(distinct ename) from #temp